# F# either monad (ROP) to to compose function with two parameters

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am using the chessie library of helper functions to do ROP (either monad)
https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/master/src/Chessie/ErrorHandling.fs

However I'm not sure how to concisely compose the following three functions together. Where `twoInputFunc` should be evaluated only if func1 and func2 return success.

```
val func1 : int -> Result<Tp1, 'a>
val func2 : string -> Result<Tp2, 'a>
val twoInputFunc : par1:Tp1 -> Tpar2:Tp2 -> Result<Ta,'a>
```

Comment: I think Chessie works beautifully for things like input handling where you really need to go through a sequence of parsing operations. However, it makes your code uglier if you use it for too many things - there is a tricky balance, but sometimes using ordinary exceptions might just be easier (as you avoid exactly this sort of thing). It's hard to say without a concrete example, but it's good to not be too religious about it :-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
let f x y = trial {
    let! a = func1 x
    let! b = func2 y
    return! twoInputFunc a b}
```

The idea is that you bind each result to `a` and `b` and then are used as input for the last function call. If either func1 or func2 results in an Error it will short circuit and return the Error.

Another way is using applicatives:

```
let g x y = flatten (twoInputFunc <!> func1 x <*> func2 y)
```

Here you apply both arguments in an Applicative style but then you will end-up with a Result of Result so you need to flatten it, this is equivalent to the monad `join` operation.

Disclaimer: I don't have Chessie installed so I didn't tried the above code, but I tried with [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) which is generic to all monads (not just Either) and it works fine (using `monad` instead of `trial` and `join` instead of `flatten`).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'll check out F#+. Is it possible you can show me this same thing using the infix operator syntax?

edit just saw that you added that too.

Comment: Ah, you mean the Applicative, yes I just added it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you suggest any F# open source projects that I can look at to see these concepts in idiomatic fashion. I have mostly only been able to see simple contrived examples and function libraries projects.

Comment: You're welcome. [Fleece](https://github.com/mausch/Fleece) uses the Either monad in [applicative style](https://github.com/mausch/Fleece/blob/83fcb9e61a62f775c3d25eaae53fa2f0c421179c/Fleece/Fleece.fs#L507) and also as a [traversable](https://github.com/mausch/Fleece/blob/83fcb9e61a62f775c3d25eaae53fa2f0c421179c/Fleece/Fleece.fs#L441).

Comment: so in this case func1 and func2 are run sequentially? Would you use f#+ parrallel array functions to make them run in parrallel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132981/discussion-between-gustavo-and-chinwobble).